# Trying to figure out how to convert function to accept piped stdin

Tags: bash, xml-parsing, stdin

I am working on a way to easily parse XML using bash for a defined purpose.  I have gotten this to work with some code I found on this site which I then recoded everything because this code worked so well.  This is currently working with a function and I have to have the data in a file to be able to process it.  Here is it in it's working state:

```
[ ~]$ cat testxml.xml
CTYPE PARTS SYSTEM "parts.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="xmlpartsstyle.css"?>
<PARTS>
   <TITLE>Computer Parts</TITLE>
   <PART>
      <ITEM>Motherboard</ITEM>
      <MANUFACTURER>ASUS</MANUFACTURER>
      <MODEL>P3B-F</MODEL>
      <COST> 123.00</COST>
   </PART>
   <PART>
      <ITEM>Video Card</ITEM>
      <MANUFACTURER>ATI</MANUFACTURER>
      <MODEL>All-in-Wonder Pro</MODEL>
      <COST> 160.00</COST>
   </PART>
   <PART>
      <ITEM>Sound Card</ITEM>
      <MANUFACTURER>Creative Labs</MANUFACTURER>
      <MODEL>Sound Blaster Live</MODEL>
      <COST> 80.00</COST>
   </PART>
   <PART>
      <ITEM> 20 inch Monitor</ITEM>
      <MANUFACTURER>LG Electronics</MANUFACTURER>
      <MODEL> 995E</MODEL>
      <COST> 290.00</COST>
   </PART>
</PARTS>

[ ~]$
[ ~]$ rdom () { local IFS=\> ; read -d \< E C ;} ; while rdom; do if [[ $E = 'PART' ]] || [[ $E = 'ITEM' ]] || [[ $E = 'COST' ]] ; then  echo $E: $C ; fi ; done < testxml.xml | xargs -L3
PART: ITEM: Motherboard COST: 123.00
PART: ITEM: Video Card COST: 160.00
PART: ITEM: Sound Card COST: 80.00
PART: ITEM: 20 inch Monitor COST: 290.00
[ ~]$
```

As you can see this pulls out the data I am looking for and I am able to reformat it to suit my needs.  However I would much rather prefer to have this accept the input from stdin such as the following:

```
cat out.xml2 | IFS=\> ; until [ EOF ]; do read -d \< E C ; if [[ $E = 'PART' ]] || [[ $E = 'ITEM' ]] || [[ $E = 'COST' ]] ; then  echo $E: $C ; fi ; done;
```

This code never ends the loop.  This may be impossible and I just don't understand how the loop is ending b/c it has "rdom" as the expression it is waiting for to show loop termination.   I've tried this with a while loop, etc.  Not sure how to determine when the data is no more so that the loop can end.  I feel like there may be a much better way restructure this that i'm completely missing although.  I like being able to use stdin b/c it allows easy use for one liners.  The actual data I am parsing is much larger and multi-dimensional.  I created this example for testing purposes.  The first example works with the large data I have though.  End result is I am trying to get this to parse from stdin rather then from a file.  Any recommendations are much appreciated.

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$ rdom() { local IFS=\> ; while read -d \< E C ; do if [[ $E = 'PART' ]] || [[ $E = 'ITEM' ]] || [[ $E = 'COST' ]] ; then  echo $E: $C ; fi ; done; }
$ rdom <out.xml2
PART: 

ITEM: Motherboard
COST:  123.00
PART: 

ITEM: Video Card
COST:  160.00
PART: 

ITEM: Sound Card
COST:  80.00
PART: 

ITEM:  20 inch Monitor
COST:  290.00
```

Or, without using the function definition but still taking input from stdin:

```
{ IFS=\> ; while read -d \< E C ; do if [[ $E = 'PART' ]] || [[ $E = 'ITEM' ]] || [[ $E = 'COST' ]] ; then  echo $E: $C ; fi ; done; } <out.xml2
```

Because the question does not show desired output, I don't know if this is what you want.

Some comments:

1. `cat out.xml2 | IFS=\> ;` sends the text of out.xml2 to the variable assignment `IFS=\>`.  After the variable assignment completes, the text is discarded.
2. `until [ EOF ]; do read -d \< E C ; ...`  does not do what you want.  In shell, the string EOF is just three characters.  By contrast, `while read -d \< E C ; do ...` will stop when the input is exhausted.

#### Examples with piping

To demonstrate that the above work with piping, not just redirection from a file, try:

```
cat out.xml2 | rdom
```

Or:

```
cat out.xml2 | { IFS=\> ; while read -d \< E C ; do if [[ $E = 'PART' ]] || [[ $E = 'ITEM' ]] || [[ $E = 'COST' ]] ; then  echo $E: $C ; fi ; done; }
```

#### Alternative output format

Continuing with the use of `cat` as a stand in for a pipeline:

```
$ cat out.xml2 | { IFS=\> ; while read -d \< E C ; do case "$E" in PART) printf "%s:" "$E";; ITEM) printf " %s: %s" "$E" "$C";; COST) printf " %s: %s\n" "$E" "$C";; esac ; done; }
PART: ITEM: Motherboard COST:  123.00
PART: ITEM: Video Card COST:  160.00
PART: ITEM: Sound Card COST:  80.00
PART: ITEM:  20 inch Monitor COST:  290.00
```

Comment: The desired output is similar to how it is in the example.  I want to be able to cat a xml file into the line and then it output as shown.  In the working example, the input must from from that file rather than being piped in.  I was hoping some file descriptor magic could be used to achieve this.  Not sure though.

Comment: @Jeff82 Both of the approaches here allow data to be piped in.   I just added examples to illustrate.

Comment: That worked great.  I was trying to take the wrong route and get rid of the loop which is necessessary for this to work.  Much appreciated  Here is my final output with the formatting which is how I was trying to get it.  Now I can use awk and reorder lines, etc:

Comment: @Jeff82 I just added some code to try to emulate the output format that you wanted.  (The code shown in not in a function but it could be.)

Comment: I got the same output using xargs:

[jjennings@shelladmindal0501 ~]$ cat testxml.xml | { IFS=\> ; while read -d \< E C ; do if [[ $E = 'PART' ]] || [[ $E = 'ITEM' ]] || [[ $E = 'COST' ]] ; then  echo $E: $C ; fi ; done; } | xargs -L2
PART: ITEM: Motherboard COST: 123.00
PART: ITEM: Video Card COST: 160.00
PART: ITEM: Sound Card COST: 80.00
PART: ITEM: 20 inch Monitor COST: 290.00
[jjennings@shelladmindal0501 ~]$

This can be reused to parse all kinds of scraped documents tho.